# Multithreaded xz, with gzip, pv, and pipes - is this the most efficient I can get?

Tags: performance, gzip, multithreading, pv, xz

I'm excited to learn that `xz` now supports multithreading:

```
xz --threads=0
```

But now I want to utilise this as much as possible.  For example, to recompress gzips as xz:

```
gzip -d -k -c myfile.gz | pv | xz -z --threads=0 - > myfile.xz
```

This results in my processor being more highly used (~260% CPU to xz, yay!).

However:

- I realise that `gzip` is not (yet) multithreading,
- I think that either `pv` or the pipes may be restricting the number of (IO?) threads.

Is this true and, if so, is there a way to make this more efficient (other than to remove `pv`)?

Comment: Can you give more details about the scenario? In my answer I point out that the number of .gz files matters a lot.

Comment: In my case it's actually one large disk image being recompressed.  I came across this because of the `gzip` 32-bit size reference limit and I wanted my compressed files to show the right uncompressed size.  There was a significant improvement in recompression, though, by about 40% compared to without threads, mostly during the nulled part of the uncompressed image where it reached 100MB/s (over USB3.0) according to `pv`.  I put this down to lower IO wait times on the `gzip` end due to more "waiting" threads on the `xz` end but I wondered whether the pipe and `pv` were a bottleneck.

Comment: And did you `time ` the difference at all between -T0 and without? Acoording to my trials it does not make a difference, you loose as much as you win.

Comment: Yes, that's how I got the ~40%, but I didn't keep a copy, sorry.

Comment: I got over 300%. So this shows that input (pipe) is the big bottleneck, not xz. It is in between my 300% and the 0.1% you get when you slow down the dd pipe with count=10 (only 10 bytes per read).

Comment: I did my tests with a 100MB file on a ramdisk. Your Q is very interseting, so it needs precision, and some testing (timing).

Comment: have you tried `pigz -d` instead of `gzip -d`?   that might improve performance a little.  `pigz -d` can't decompress in parallel - however, it can run 4 threads at a time (one each for reading, writing, checksum calcs, and decompression). see `man pigz` for details.   If it's not packaged for your distribution, you can find pigz at http://zlib.net/pigz/ - in debian etc, `sudo apt-get install pigz`

Comment: @cas: "pigz...which can speed up decompression under some circumstances." This must be multiple files on a good system. "specially prepared deflate streams " seem to be the workaround.

Comment: @cas I injstalled pigz and tested - this is really a faster decompression, even though the algorithm itself is on one core, as you explain. Overall decompression is only about 1/4 of the work, so pigz here is only secondary. Thanks to your hint I made some tests, see my answer.

Comment: It might be an idea to use GNU parallel to run several processes at once, then each one might only use a single core/thread, but the ones running simultaneously will probably use different cores/threads.

Answer (score 3):

With the `-T0` multithread option you tell xz two things at once. To use MT also means: **wait** until all input (data) is read into memory, and then start to compress in "parallel".

After including `pigz` into my tests I analyze the perfomance step by step; I have a 100M file `f100`.

```
$  time xz -c  f100 >/dev/null

real  0m2.658s
user  0m2.573s
sys   0m0.083s
```

99% of the time is spent compressing on one core. With all four cores activated with `-T4` (or `-T0`)

```
$  time xz -c -T4 f100 >/dev/null

real  0m0.825s
user  0m2.714s
sys   0m0.284s
```

Overall result: 300% faster, almost linear per core. The "user" value must be divided by 4, the way it is reported/defined. "sys" now shows some overhead -- real is the sum of 1/4 user plus sys.

```
$  time gzip     -dc f100.gz >/dev/null
$  time pigz -p4 -dc f100.gz >/dev/null
```

This is 0.5 vs. 0.2 seconds; when I put all together:

```
$  time pigz -dc -p4 f100.gz | xz -c -T4 >out.xz

real  0m0.902s
user  0m3.237s
sys   0m0.363s
```

...it reduces 0.8 + 0.2 = 0.9.

With **multiple files**, but not too multiple, you can get highest overall parallelism with 4 shell background processes. Here I use four 25M files instead:

`for f in f25-?.gz; do time pigz -p4  -dc "$f" | xz -c -T0 >"$f".xz & done`

This seems even slightly faster with 0.7s. And even without multithreading, even for `xz`:

`for f in f25-?.gz; do time gzip  -dc "$f" | xz -c  >"$f".xz & done`

just by setting up four simple quarter pipelines with `&`, you get 0.8s, same as for a 100M file with `xz -T4`.

In my scenario it is about just as important to activate multithreading in `xz` than it is to parallelize the whole pipeline; if you can combine this with pigz and/or multiple files, you can even be a bit faster than a quarter of the sum of the single steps.